# Assembly infinite loop (jmp -2)

Tags: assembly, nasm, infinite-loop

I heard that with a jmp -2 we could make an infinite loop. It sounded weird but after the explanation that a relative jump would take one byte, the next instruction address (eip) would be 2 bytes less than the jmp address. So, I decided to implement that but I can't make it work.
That's my source code:

```
SECTION .text

global main
main:
   push   ebp
   mov    esp, ebp
   jmp    0x-2
   leave
   ret
```

And used this to compile:

```
nasm -f elf asmloop.asm -o objasmloop.o
```

```
 ld -m elf_i386 -o execasmloop -e main objasmloop.o
```

I also tried to use the hex value of -2 (FE) but still get segmentation fault.
After all, I took a look at the disassembly with GDB:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08048060 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048061 <+1>: mov    %ebp,%esp
   0x08048063 <+3>: jmp    0xfffffffe
   0x08048068 <+8>: leave  
   0x08048069 <+9>: ret
```

I was able to see on this dump that the actual difference between jmp address and leave address is in fact 5 bytes (it's not using the short reference jmp). But I tried with this to and the result was the same (segmentation fault). How can I perform that kind of infinite-loop?

Comment: What assembler are you using? Some of them require that you explicitly indicate a SHORT jump, as opposed to a NEAR jump. Your disassembly doesn't show code bytes, so I can't tell, other than that a `jmp short -2` should be only 2 bytes (`EB FE`). Aside from that, it is rather unclear why you would want to do this. What good is an infinite loop that performs absolutely no operations with no way to ever bail out?

Comment: @CodyGray : From the OPs question he is using NASM

Comment: Does NASM support `0x-2`? That's just weird.

Comment: Yep,I believe `0x` is seen the same as `0x0` so `0x-2` would be `0x0-2` or simply `-2`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ah, that at least makes some kind of sense. Makes me further think the OP is a bit confused though since that seems to be a very complex way to write `-2`.

Comment: @CodyGray I saw this thing as an example on an assembly course for malware analysis.

Comment: start with here: jmp here or here: jmp short here.  and then assemble and disassemble that, assuming you get the instruction you wanted, now you need to play with various syntax tricks to see if you can generate the same instruction.

Answer (score 8):

`jmp -2` will jump to **the address** -2 (or `0ff..fffeh`), at least in NASM.
As far as I know, the operand of a direct jump is always the target address, leaving the computation of the relative *immediate*, encoded in the opcode, to the assembler.

In short, `jmp SHORT -2` if placed at offset 0, is assembled as `EB FC` which can be seen, with a new syntax, as `jmp <-4>` since 2+(-4) = -2.

If you want to craft opcodes, you need to revert to the pseudo instructions `db`, `dw` and so on.

If you just want to loop without a label, you can always use the `$` symbol, that refer to the offset/address/counter of the current instruction/symbol.
So a `jmp <-2>` is simply a `jmp $`, that for a jump placed at zero is equivalent to `jmp 0` and assembled as `EB FE` as you expected.

Being `$` a symbol, you can perform ordinary arithmetic on it: `jmp $-2` is `EB FC` or `jmp <-4>`.

Comment: Thank you @Margaret, that was pretty helpful ;).